# clearify concept of '^' in c++

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

I have just started learning c++, in c++ programming some times I have to use `^` after string for example

```
string^ abc;
```

And sometimes there is no need of `^` and we can write our line as

```
string abc;
```

This confuse me a lot, I don't know when to use `^` and when to ignore it. I know its a foolish question but I desperately need to clear my concept of `^` so please tell me when to use and when to ignore `^` in c++.

Comment: [Handle to Object Operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yk97tc08.aspx)

Comment: To make this a bit more clear, `string^` is part of C++/CLI, a C++ extension for the .NET runtime. It is not part of Standard C++.

Comment: Just be aware that this isn't something in standard C++, it's an artifact of Microsoft's attempt to integrate it with .NET.